# Read quorum in CouchDb for _find and MapReduce queries

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-mango

The [CouchDb documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/cluster/sharding.html#quorum) indicates that, by default, both reads and writes to single documents are quorum reads and writes (e.g. `r=2` and `w=2` in a 3-replica system).

However, [the documentation for `_find`](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html) says r "defaults to 1, in which case the document found in the index is returned. If set to a higher value, each document is read from at least that many replicas before it is returned..." It is not 100% clear to me however what exactly that means. If I run `_find` with `r=2` and I find a document in the index of a single node I think it's fairly clear that it will also fetch that document from a 2nd node and return the latest to me. However, I *think* it's still only checking the index on one node so consistency in a healthy cluster isn't guaranteed.

For example, suppose I have a healthy 3 node cluster with no network partitions. The DB in this cluster has a Mango index that includes field `foo` and I query, via `_find`, for all documents with `foo=bar`. Let's say that initially document `X` has value `foo=baz` so that `X` should not be returned. Now, I update `X` setting `foo=bar` and I do this with `w=2`. I then immediately re-run my `_find` with `r=2`. If the **index** is only consulted on one node then I'm not guaranteed to have `X` returned by my query even with `r=2`. So does `r=2` mean only that documents found in one node's index will also be looked up on a 2nd node or does it mean that the index on 2 nodes will run the query and have their results merged.

Also, it seems like the same index and `r=1` default would likely apply to JavaScript MapReduce views, but I see [no equivalent documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html) for that case. Do MapReduce view queries default to `r=1` or `r=2`?

Answer (score 0):

I posted a link to the above on the CouchDb Slack and [got a response](https://couchdb.slack.com/archives/C49LEE7NW/p1596145375243500):

> map/reduce views (accessed by _view) are r=1 and the r parameter mentioned for _find I think only refers to when we fetch the document, not when the query itself runs, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

It's not quite a definitive answer so I'm not marking this correct but it is definitely more information that I had before.

Comment: I think a quorum for view queries is impractical, if not outright impossible in some cases, due to the eventual-consistency nature of CouchDB. To ensure a view quorum, a quorum of nodes would effectively have to "freeze the world", make sure they've received the same updates, then return a result.  That would pretty well go against the intention of eventual consistency. So I expect there's an implicit quorum of 1 for every index lookup, and to match that, the document retrieval also uses r=1 by default.

Comment: ... r=2 would thus presumably query a single index, but then verify the document from 2 nodes before returning it. (of course: only for queries that actually return documents)

Comment: @Flimzy, that makes sense. It does cause some difficulty for the programmer at times but it does make sense.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve? Or just asking out of curiosity?

Comment: @Flimzy there is a specific problem but explaining it would take a very long time. I think I've got what I need here. Thanks!